# Increase password input character size without affecting placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to increase the font size of an HTML password input WITHOUT affecting the placeholder? In other words, I want to scale up the size of the password symbols (bullets).

Naturally, I tried increasing the `font-size` of `input[type="password"]`. This worked perfectly, but it makes my placeholder font increase too:

[image]

Is there a work around to prevent my placeholder from being affected? I know that you can specifically target them using `::-webkit-input-placeholder` or `:-moz-placeholder` - but that applies it globally and basically defeats the purpose of my question.

Any HTML, CSS or Javascript/jQuery solutions are welcome.

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you need, but why not wrap the `input` in a `span` and style `span.someClass ::-webkit-input-placeholder`?

Comment: I thought using pseudo classes such as `::-webkit-input-placeholder` behind a class was bad practice/bug prone?

Comment: @lonesomeday It works, but see how the placeholder becomes buggy: http://jsfiddle.net/ZXLQd/

Comment: Just don’t use placeholders instead of labels, and you won’t be creating this problem in the first place.

Comment: That's a bit unrealistic. Which one do you prefer? http://imgkk.com/i/3xjx.jpg  vs.  http://imgkk.com/i/uc7r.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did't find a accurate solutions of your problem. But i make a fiddle with some javascript/jquery code to resolve your problem.

**HTML**

```
 <input id="txtInput" type="password" placeholder="Passowrd" onchange="CheckModification();" onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();"/>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#txtInput').focus(function () {
        if ($('#txtInput').val() == "") {
             $('#txtInput').css('font-size', '14px');
         }
         else {
             $('#txtInput').css('font-size', '24px');
         }
     });

     $('#txtInput').blur(function () {
         if ($('#txtInput').val() == "") {
             $('#txtInput').css('font-size', '14px');
         }
         else {
             $('#txtInput').css('font-size', '24px');
         }
     });
 });

function CheckModification(){
         if ($('#txtInput').val() == "") {
             $('#txtInput').css('font-size', '14px');
         }
         else {
             $('#txtInput').css('font-size', '24px');
         }
     }
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXLQd/3/)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: It's not the cleanest solution, but it works - and that's good enough for me!